# Lowest value not been displayed

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, struct, max

I can't display the student comparing per subject with lowest marks, highest marks is working fine. Is there a mistake in implementation in loop or else didn't I set the correct parameter to search the element with lowest value, what could be the reason?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    int roll_no;
    int semester_no;
    char name[20];
    int marks[6];

}semester[100];

int main ()
{
    int i=0,n,j=0;
    int highest=0,lowest=0;

    printf("HOW MANY STUDENTS MARKS TO ENTER?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("ENTER DETAILS OF STUDENT %d",i+1);
        printf("\nROLL NO\n");
        scanf("%d",&semester[i].roll_no);
        printf("NAME\n");
        getchar();
        gets(semester[i].name);
        printf("SEMESTER\n");
        scanf("%d",&semester[i].semester_no);

    int maxmarks=semester[0].marks[0];

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            if(semester[i].marks[j]>maxmarks)
            {
                 highest=i;

            }
        }

    }

    minmarks=semester[0].marks[0];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            if(semester[i].marks[j]<minmarks)
            {
                lowest=i;
            }
        }
    }
   // printf("\n%d\n",cl);
   // printf("%d\n",ch);

    printf("\nNAME OF STUDENT WITH HIGHEST MARKS\n");
    printf("%s",semester[highest].name);
    printf("\nNAME OF THE STUDENT WITH LOWEST MARKS\n");
    printf("%s",semester[lowest].name);

    return 0;

}
```

I tried with different input, but I get wrong output

```
HOW MANY STUDENTS MARKS TO ENTER?
2
ENTER DETAILS OF STUDENT 1
ROLL NO
1
NAME
abc
SEMESTER
1
SUBJECT 1 MARKS
10
SUBJECT 2 MARKS
20
SUBJECT 3 MARKS
30
SUBJECT 4 MARKS
40
SUBJECT 5 MARKS
50
ENTER DETAILS OF STUDENT 2
ROLL NO
2
NAME
xyz
SEMESTER
1
SUBJECT 1 MARKS
50
SUBJECT 2 MARKS
60
SUBJECT 3 MARKS
70
SUBJECT 4 MARKS
80
SUBJECT 5 MARKS
90

NAME OF STUDENT WITH HIGHEST MARKS
xyz
NAME OF THE STUDENT WITH LOWEST MARKS
xyz
```

Comment: More descriptive variable names would help this question a lot. It's confusing as is.

Comment: To improve the readability of your code, you should name your variables after their purpose. It is hard to guess, what rn, s, and sn are for. You should also adjust your identitaion.

Comment: Smaller code is not better code. Readability is much more important.

Comment: @Sujit Maiti What do you mean by saying "the person with lowest marks"? Does it mean that all marks of the person should be less than the marks of other person?

Comment: @Sujit Maiti You should provide input data and what is wrong. with them.

Comment: lowest marks comparing each subject at a time, and displaying the name comparing all subjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a stand-alone program that you can use to figure out how to fix your program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student {
    int roll_no;
    int semester_no;
    char name[20];
    int marks[6];
} semester[100];

int main () {
    int i = 0, n, j = 0;
    int highest = 0, lowest = 0;

    printf("marks?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("roll?\n");
        scanf("%d", &semester[i].roll_no);
        printf("name?\n");
        scanf("%s", semester[i].name);
        printf("semester?\n");
        scanf("%d", &semester[i].semester_no);
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            printf("%d marks\n", j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &semester[i].marks[j]);
        }
    }

    int maxmarks = semester[0].marks[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
            if (semester[i].marks[j] > maxmarks) {
                highest = i;
                maxmarks = semester[i].marks[j];
            }
        }
    }

    int minmarks = semester[0].marks[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if (semester[i].marks[j] < minmarks) {
                lowest = i;
                minmarks = semester[i].marks[j];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("NAME OF STUDENT WITH HIGHEST MARKS\n");
    printf("%s\n", semester[highest].name);
    printf("NAME OF THE STUDENT WITH LOWEST MARKS\n");
    printf("%s\n", semester[lowest].name);

    return 0;
}
```

I tested it with this script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
./scratch << EOF
2
1
abc
1
10
20
30
40
50
60
2
xyz
1
50
60
70
80
90
100
EOF
```

**Output**

```
marks?
roll?
name?
semester?
1 marks
2 marks
3 marks
4 marks
5 marks
6 marks
roll?
name?
semester?
1 marks
2 marks
3 marks
4 marks
5 marks
6 marks

NAME OF STUDENT WITH HIGHEST MARKS
xyz
NAME OF THE STUDENT WITH LOWEST MARKS
abc
```

Comment: Did you change both loops?

Comment: Then the problem is in the code you are not showing us.

Comment: It works now, could you explain where I went wrong?

Comment: It looks like you still haven't put your complete program in your question. Without the complete program, I can't tell you where you went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You have to update `maxmarks`and `minmarks` in the loops.  Something like this:

```c
maxmarks=semester[0].marks[0];
minmarks=semester[0].marks[0];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if (semester[i].marks[j] > maxmarks) {
           highest = i;
           maxmarks = semester[i].marks[j];
        }
        if (semester[i].marks[j] < minmarks) {
           lowest = i;
           minmarks = semester[i].marks[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see 'n' being set or even any input being taken from the user, but I assume you removed that part for some inexplicable reason.

Now to the problem: 'm' is an array of 6 elements but you are only iterating from 1 to 5. This means you are ignoring the marks for the first subject of every student, as far as I can guess from your code.

Answer (score 0):

On line 23: `for (i=0;i<n;i++)` you would have more deterministic behavior if `n` had a predefined value. As it stands in line 16: `int i=0,n,j=0;` `n`'s values is not defined.

Comment: I'm taking n as the number of students in input part of the code

Comment: @SujitMaiti But you are using `n` before it is set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you selected a wrong approach.

Within the outer loop you have to set a current maximum or minimum value for a given student. And in the inner loop you have to calculate the maximum or minimum for the student. Then you have to compare this maximum or minimum value with the value that was set outside the loops.

For example

```
int maxmarks=semester[0].marks[0];

for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    int current_max = semester[i].marks[0];

    for ( j = 1; j < 6; j++ )
    {
        if( current_max < semester[i].marks[j] )
        {
             current_max = semester[i].marks[j];
        }
    }

    if ( maxmarks < current_max ) highest = i; 
}
```